# Exchangeability and conditional i.i.d. property

Tags: probability-theory

Consider a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal A, P)$ and a sequence of random variables $(X_i)_i = X_1, X_2, \ldots$.

$(X_i)$ is called exchangeable, if the joint distribution of every finite subset of $k$ of these random variables depends only on $k$.

$(X_i)$ is called conditionally i.i.d. with respect to a $\sigma$-field $\mathcal F \subseteq \mathcal A$, if $(X_i)$ are conditionally independent given $\mathcal F$, and $P[X_i \in A | \mathcal F] = P[ X_j \in A | \mathcal F]$ for every $A\in\mathcal A$ almost surely.

It is known that, the exchageablity of $(X_i)$ is equivalent to the property that $(X_i)$ are conditionally i.i.d. with respect to some $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal T$.

*Question*: Can a sequence $(X_i)$ be conditionally i.i.d. with respect to some $\mathcal F$ but fail to be exchangeable?